# PHPOffice PHPSpreadsheet corrupted excel file

Tags: php, excel, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Working with PHPSpreadsheet to create a customized spreadsheet. We have two servers. On the first with ubuntu+apache all works fine . However, with the same code on the second server (centos+nginx) we have corrupted file. Code is:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bitrix/vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'hello world');
$writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);
ob_clean();
$writer->save($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/upload/helloworld.xls');
```

First file:
[good file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSdM6.png)
Second file: [bad file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7pKy.png)

Same with xlsx.
nginx/1.0;
10.4.17-MariaDB; php v7.2.34;  phpoffice/phpword 0.17.0; phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.15